# Installing Keras/Tensorflow in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to install Keras/Tensorflow as per the sequence mentioned [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/getting-started-with-deep-learning-using-keras-in-r/)

It was fine till I installed "tensorflow" using install.packages("tensorflow") but when I tried "install_tensorflow()" function call, it was throwing the following error

```
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None
Error: Error 1 occurred creating conda environment r-tensorflow
```

I tried uninstalling Anaconda and reinstalled a clean version of it and then I tried the above steps, still the same error. I tried installing reticulate package as per other posts but even that is throwing an error like

```
In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\<user>\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\00LOCK\reticulate\libs\x64\reticulate.dll to C:\Users\<user>\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\reticulate\libs\x64\reticulate.dll: Permission denied
```

I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong here. Is there any step that I am missing ? I've used RGui, RStudio, Visual Studio and even  R cmd shell as well. Same issue everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried initializing R from the directory in which your anaconda environment is located?

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately the same issue and same error

Error: Error 1 occurred creating conda environment r-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

I checked all of the suggestions. None of them worked. This worked for me on Windows 10

1- Open rstudio and uninstall these package if you already installed using:

```
uninstall.packages(c("keras", "tensorflow","tfruns"))
```

2- uninstall rtools from your computer if exists

3- Install Anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

4- Install the last version of rtools from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

5- Close rstudio if it is opened

6- open new session and write this:

```
install.packages("reticulate")
install.packages("remotes")
library("reticulate")
remotes::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(version = "2.0.0b1", method = "conda", envname = "r-reticulate")

remotes::install_github("rstudio/keras", dependencies = TRUE)
library(keras)
```

7- check if they work:

#if tensorflow works

```
tf$abs(-1)
```

#if keras works

```
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
```